# Heroku django admin panel looks like not normal

Tags: django, heroku, interface

Im created a heroku server. I did all setups, urls etc. But when I trying access to django admin panel using https://demoherokutest48.herokuapp.com/admin/ all css contents disappear. I dont know why happening. But all sql tables prefectly transfered to heroku. Only css contents disappeared.
Note: I tryed run at local in my pc. Its perfectly worked. I think problem is about at heroku.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem. I just install whitenoise and added to settings.py/MIDDLEWARE

```
        MIDDLEWARE = [
      # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
      # ...
    ]
```

[documentation](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)